# get response from cloud function inside another one

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have in my cloud code this two functions What I'm trying to do is calling one function from another one (hello from count). The problem is the success block in the `run` function isn't executed and the console remain silent. What to do ?

Count Function :

```
Parse.Cloud.define('count', function(request, response) {

var query = new Parse.Query('MyClass');
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {

      Parse.Cloud.run('hello', {}, {
       success: function(result) {
         console.log('What is the result ? ' + result);
       },
       error: function(error) {
       }
       });
      response.success(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```

Hello Function :

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(request, response) {
 response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `hello` function is executed asynchronously but before it finishes, your code already has hit `response.success(results);`. You either need to move the `response.success();` to your `hello` success block or you need to use Promises.

Comment: Can I ask you other questions related to this code @Mo Nazemi ?

Comment: is there a good guide to learn promises ? I'm trying to make a for loop contain http requests but it keep send me errors can we meet at the chat here to discuss the code ?

Comment: First of all, have you read the [Promises section](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises) from Parse documentation ?